# Use decltype on inherited template static member function using GCC

Tags: c++11, inheritance, static-methods, decltype, gcc4.9

I have the below working code available on [coliru.stacked-crooked.com](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dcf208438edb917d).

As `static std::false_type check(...)` is duplicated, I wonder if we could factorize it. For instance within a base class. As pointed out by [Jonathan Wakely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29013355/938111) my attempt at the bottom of my question compiles using Clang, but not using GCC.

I have tried many possibilities but it seems impossible to use `decltype` on inherited template static function using GCC.

Questions: 
1. **Is GCC-4.9 compliant with C++11 standard on this point?**
2. **What is the GCC-compliant workaround to use `decltype` on inherited template static member function?**

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
struct is_addable
{
  template<typename U> static std::false_type check(...);
  template<typename U> static auto            check(int) 
       -> decltype( std::declval<U>() + std::declval<U>(), std::true_type{});
  using type = decltype(check<T>(0));
};

template<typename T>
struct is_multiplicable
{
  template<typename U> static std::false_type check(...);
  template<typename U> static auto            check(int)
    -> decltype( std::declval<U>() * std::declval<U>(), std::true_type{});
  using type = decltype(check<T>(0));
};

int main()
{
  std::cout <<"is_addable\n";
  std::cout <<" long:   "<< is_addable<long>::type::value        <<'\n';
  std::cout <<" string: "<< is_addable<std::string>::type::value <<'\n';
  std::cout <<" void:   "<< is_addable<void>::type::value        <<'\n';

  std::cout <<"is_multiplicable\n";
  std::cout <<" long:   "<< is_multiplicable<long>::type::value        <<'\n';
  std::cout <<" string: "<< is_multiplicable<std::string>::type::value <<'\n';
  std::cout <<" void:   "<< is_multiplicable<void>::type::value        <<'\n';
}
```

#### One of my attempts

**Edit:** added `template<typename U>` as pointed out by [Jonathan Wakely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29013355/938111)

```
struct default_check
{ 
  template<typename U>
  static std::false_type check(...);
};

template<typename T>
struct is_addable : default_check
{
  using default_check::check;

  template<typename U> static auto check(int) 
       -> decltype( std::declval<U>() + std::declval<U>(), std::true_type{});

  using type = decltype(check<T>(0));
};
```

#### GCC-4.9.2 fails on [coliru.stacked-crooked.com](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82a140b210aa6771)

```
> g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -Wfatal-errors main.cpp
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'struct is_addable<void>':
main.cpp:38:63:   required from here
main.cpp:19:30: error: no matching function for call to 'is_addable<void>::check(int)'
   using type = decltype(check<T>(0));
                              ^
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

#### Clang-3.4.1 succeeds on [godbolt.org](http://goo.gl/CTS1Pc)

```
> clang++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -Wfatal-errors
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `default_check::check` is not a template, so you can't call it like `check<T>(0)`

The solution is simply to make it a function template:

```
struct default_check
{
  template<typename T>  // <-- ADD THIS LINE
    static std::false_type check(...);
};
```

Clang accepts that, but GCC still won't compile that (not sure why) so I'd just give up on `default_check` and write `check` everywhere you need it, as you had originally. It's clearer anyway.

Comment: [Works in clang but fails with g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a4db5f2584c11db)

Comment: ...or default the type parameter for the function template: `template <class U = T> static auto check(int)` and evaluate as `using type = decltype(check(0))`.

Comment: OK Jonathan and @0x499602D2. It is my fault : I have forgotten `template<typename U>` when quickly wrote one attempt. I thought it was not compiling using Clang. Therefore I have change a bit my question: Is there a workaround for GCC? Cheers

Comment: Hi @Casey. Please could you provide an answer (with your complete snippet). Cheers :-)

Comment: Hi Jonathan. Should I rollback my edits and create a new question? What do you advice?

Answer (score 4):

I was going to suggest simplifying your syntax by defaulting the type parameter of the `check` function template in the derived classes:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_addable : default_check
{
  using default_check::check;

  template<typename U = T> static auto check(int) 
       -> decltype(std::declval<U>() + std::declval<U>(), std::true_type{});

  using type = decltype(check(0));
};
```

but [clang and gcc disagree on how to resolve the overload set](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dcb2b74906590584). GCC apparently doesn't believe that the non-template `check` inherited from `default_check` is viable.

In any case, especially if you're going to have several of these traits, it would seem simpler to factor out "SFINAE check of a binary operation" into a template:

```
template<class...>
struct voider { using type = void; };
template<class...Ts>
using void_t = typename voider<Ts...>::type;

template <class T, class U, class BinaryOperation, class Enable = void>
struct is_binop_able_ : std::false_type {};
template <class T, class U, class BinOp>
struct is_binop_able_<T, U, BinOp, void_t<
  decltype(std::declval<BinOp>()(
    std::declval<T>(), std::declval<U>()))>> :
  std::true_type {};

template <class T, class U, class BinOp>
using is_binop_able = typename is_binop_able_<T,U,BinOp>::type;
```

and create an alias for each of the desired traits that instantiates
that template with a generic function object type that implements the desired operation:

```
#define RETURNS(...) \
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
    ->decltype(__VA_ARGS__) { \
      return (__VA_ARGS__); \
  }

struct plus {
  template <class T, class U>
  auto operator()(T t, U u) RETURNS(t + u)
};
template<class T, class U = T>
using is_addable = is_binop_able<T, U, plus>;

struct multiplies {
  template <class T, class U>
  auto operator()(T t, U u) RETURNS(t * u)
};
template<class T, class U = T>
using is_multiplicable = is_binop_able<T, U, multiplies>;
```

It's slightly less code per trait template, and you get handy reusable generic binary function object types as a nice side effect. The other nice side effect is that both GCC and clang compile it correctly: [**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/21646f9dc5b30aed).

As [@0x499602D2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29013260/use-decltype-on-inherited-template-static-member-function-using-gcc/29014938?noredirect=1#comment46277818_29014938) states in a comment, the `void` specializations of the C++14 standard library function objects are almost exactly identical to the generic binary function objects implemented herein. If your library has C++14 implementations of them you could simply use them instead of writing your own ([**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f96b91eb5f9fb2f) with GCC only, [clang up to 3.6 blows up on `is_multiplicable<std::string>`](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/sjJBOLdwJwlN7pzl), although [clang trunk compiles it correctly](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/sjJBOLdwJwlN7pzl)):

```
template<class T, class U = T>
using is_addable = is_binop_able<T, U, std::plus<>>;

template<class T, class U = T>
using is_multiplicable = is_binop_able<T, U, std::multiplies<>>;
```

Comment: Couldn't you use `std::plus<>` and `std::multiplies<>` in place of your own?

Comment: @0x499602D2 `std::plus` et al. aren't useful in SFINAE context since they are unconstrained. E.g. [`is_addable<void>` would result in a compile error inside `std::plus` instead of the desired SFINAE in `is_addable`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19de0aa39ce943af).

Comment: I was referring to the specialization of [`std::plus<void>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus_void) in C++14 that deduces the arguments.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yes, C++14-compliant implementations of the std function objects would work fine, modulo the missing conditional `noexcept` specifications. (I'm a bit overzealous about `noexcept`.)